# Make a member which cannot login

Tags: members

Is there a way to make a member which cannot be logged in?

I am using it as some sort of a member placeholder for entries of members I want to delete.

I don't want anyone be able to log-in as that member.

Does this feature exist?

Comment: If you're making the member then how can anyone log in as that member if they don't know the password? Please explain your situation in detail.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the access to the Control Panel to a Member Group if you want to: [Members > members groups](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#control-panel-access).

The **Banned Member Group**, for example, can't access the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of goes against the philosophy of having members to actually have 1 that cannot login. If your posts are member restricted then you'll need to have a member that you can assign them to with the same level of permissions.

If security is an issue:

Create a new member, assign them whatever group is required then set a monster 64 char password, don't record the password and move on.